# Formatting S3 BucketSize Logs for Logstash

Tags: json, amazon-s3, logstash

I am trying for a solution to show the S3 BucketSize information in Kibana using ELK Stack. I need S3 BucketSize information stored in S3 Bucket and then read the files through Logstash. Hope this would solve viewing historical data. Since I am new to ELK, I am petty not sure how to get this work.

I have tried below things to work, but did not go well...

Using [ncdu-s3](https://github.com/EverythingMe/ncdu-s3) tool I have S3 BucketSize details in JSON format. I am trying to put that into Logstash and it is throwing error as below.

The JSON file format is

```
[1,0,{"timestamp":1469370986,"progver":"0.1","progname":"ncdu-s3"},
[{"name":"s3:\/\/BucketName\/FolderName1"},
[{"name":"FolderName1"},
{"dsize":107738,"name":"File1.rar"},
{"dsize":532480,"name":"File2.rar"},
[{"name":"FolderName2"},
{"dsize":108890,"name":"File3.rar"}]]]
```

I use the below command

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/1' -d @/home/ubuntu/filename.json
```

ERROR:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[Malformed content, must start with an object]","status":400}
```

I think I need to format the JSON file in order to work... Do anyone suggest a good way to go?